# Use Sendgrid to send email from Next Application hosted on Vercel

Tags: next.js, import, sendgrid, vercel

I can't figure out how to make this import work while my application is hosted on Vercel:
`import sendgrid from "@sendgrid/mail";`

While the app compiles the following error pops up:
`./pages/api/contact.js Module not found: Can't resolve '@sendgrid/mail'`

Indeed i believe the Sendgrid packages are not installed on the server. Does it make sense in a Serverless context?

What is the right approach to make this work?

I tried to comment the line to try to anderstand if the Sendgrid package was somehow part of the packages allowed or installed on the server that resulted havving a error 500 page.

Answer (score 0):

Can you confirm that `@sendgrid/mail` is listed as a dependency in the `package.json`?

If so, try to import the `MailService` property instead of using the default:

```js
import { MailService } from "@sendgrid/mail";

const sendgridClient = new MailService();

sendgridClient.setApiKey(process.env.SENDGRID_API_KEY || "");
```

Answer (score 0):

I initially install `npm install @sendgrid@lastest` which wasn't including the 'mail' subpackage and this is why it was not found by Vercel.

I `npm install @sendgrid/mail`, it then was declared into package-lock.json and all went fine.